# Haskell define a function

Tags: function, haskell

I have to make a function like this:

```
success :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Int -> (Int,Int,Int) -> Bool
```

(Int,Int,Int) First three Ints are attributes (that means numbers from 1 to 20)

Int in the middle  is the one to compare the differences between attributes and dices.

(Int,Int,Int) the last three Ints are diced by a dice with 20 sides for each of them.

```
sucess (attribute 1,attribute 2, attribute 3) -> Compare difference between attributes and dices -> (Dice 1,Dice 2,Dice 3) -> Bool
```

Now I have to compare attribute 1 and dice 1 and so on.
If the dice is higher then the attribute, I've to notice the difference.
If lower I've to notice 0. If the three differences are higher than the difficult I lose 
=> function is false

For example:

```
success (16,13,8) 4 (1,17,10)  => false difference is 6
success (16,13,8) 4 (1,10, 9)  => true difference is only 1!
```

I am a newby at haskell-programming and have no idea how to handle this.

Comment: Would you are to elaborate? I read it a few times but I don't quite get what you are saying :/

Comment: So, `success (a₁,a₂,a₃) c (d₁,d₂,d₃)` is supposed to consider each difference `dᵢ - aᵢ` (but not if `aᵢ > dᵢ`), and return `False` if any of them is larger than `c`. Is that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Do you mean to handle an argument tuple `(a, b, c) d (x, y, z)` in the following way: get the sum of `max(x-a,0)`, `max(y-b,0)`, `max(z-c,0)` and compare it with `d`? It's hard to guess what is that you exactly want. Please edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: By the example, I figure it's the sum larger than `c`, not any of them larger than `c`. In the first example, the sum of (17-13) and (10-8) is 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a homework assigment, you're supposed to do it by yourself. So I will offer some hints instead of the full working solution.

You could define that function by using pattern matching:

```
success (a1, a2, a3) d (d1, d2, d3) = ... -- put condition at here
    where diff1 = ...
          diff2 = ...
          diff3 = ...
```

I believe you can fill in the missing details quite easily.

Comment: No, I want to create a simple game in Haskell.

Comment: @user3433232 Whether it is or not, can you figure out how to do it now?

Comment: `if ... then True else False` is not good advice. That's always equivalent to the `...` alone.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, but that made the intention clearer. Maybe I should replace that with a comment.

Comment: where diff1 = if (d1 > a1) then d1-a1  Is that right?

Comment: @user3433232 No need to use if when defining the differences. Put your if's in the condition, checking if the differences are higher than `d`. Even better, do not use if's at all, but exploit the boolean operators (AND is `&&`, OR is `||`).

Comment: @user3433232 In Haskell, `else` clause is not an optional part of `if` expression. You can define `diff1` as `diff1 = if (d1 > a1) then d1-a1 else 0` or `diff1 = max (d1-a1) 0`.